# Generate colors based on unique entries in another list in R

Tags: r, colors, igraph

I want to use a color palette to define colors for my graph edges in *igraph*. I have create the color palette using `RColorBrewer` and need to assign a unique color to each edge based on edge attribute information.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
colrs<- brewer.pal(length(unique(E(g)$fruit)), "Accent")  
E(g)$color <- colrs[E(g)$fruit]  #Does not work
E(g)$color
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [79] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Is there a way I can use the `E(g)$fruit` as an index into the `colrs` list?

There are 4 types of fruits in `E(g)$fruit`:

```
unique(E(g)$fruit)
"Apple"       "Orange"      "Grapes"     "Pear"
```

Thus depending on what type of *fruit* each edge has, it should get the corresponding color from the `colrs` list such that all edges with "Apple" have the same color, all edges with "Orange" has the same color and so on and so forth. I will eventually plot the graph with the following code:

```
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.color='grey80', vertex.label.color="black", edge.color=E(g)$color)
```

Here is a sample of the edgelist of my graph:

```
  from   to    fruit
1 A      B     Apple
2 A      C     Apple
3 B      C     Grapes
4 D      B     Pear
5 D      C     Orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your `colrs` vector by the unique `E(g)$fruit`:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
  from   to    fruit
1 A      B     Apple
2 A      C     Apple
3 B      C     Grapes
4 D      B     Pear
5 D      C     Orange")
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
colrs<- brewer.pal(length(unique(E(g)$fruit)), "Accent")  
names(colrs) <- unique(E(g)$fruit)
E(g)$color <- colrs[E(g)$fruit]  #Does not work
E(g)$color
# [1] "#7FC97F" "#7FC97F" "#BEAED4" "#FDC086" "#FFFF99"
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.color='grey80', vertex.label.color="black", edge.color=E(g)$color)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar code but I needed a bigger color pallet (more then 8 provided in "Accent"), we can use the `colorRampPalette` function for that. That way we can create our own palette with the amount of colors we need.

```
colourCount = length(unique(g$fruit))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
colrs<- getPalette(colourCount)
names(colrs) <- unique(E(g)$fruit)
E(g)$color <- colrs[E(g)$fruit]  
E(g)$color
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.color='grey80', vertex.label.color="black", edge.color=E(g)$color)
```