# R color vertex igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a database with all the users and their roles, i've made a table that has usera, role, userb. i'm trying to give each user a color based on their team.

the SQL code below can be used to create a similar dataset

```
select concat('H',ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 999999)) acentralacc, CONCAT('Role_',CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))))role,concat('H',ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 999999))bcentralacc
select concat('H',ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 999999)) centralaccountname, CONCAT('Team_',CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))))team
```

'

```
#get library's
install.packages("igraph")
library("igraph")

#edges (connection between users)
connStr <- "Driver={SQL Server};MyCon;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"
dsSqlServerData <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery = "SELECT top 100000 * FROM MyTable1", connectionString = connStr)
data <- rxDataStep(dsSqlServerData)
    head(data)
  acentralacc                   rol bcentralacc
1     H000062 ADDN_Basis_BBE_intern     H000079
2     H000062 ADDN_Basis_BBE_intern     H000082
3     H000062 ADDN_Basis_BBE_intern     H000092
4     H000062 ADDN_Basis_BBE_intern     H000170
5     H000062 ADDN_Basis_BBE_intern     H000197
6     H000062 ADDN_Basis_BBE_intern     H000233
data$rol <- 1
    head(data)
  acentralacc rol bcentralacc
1     H000062   1     H000079
2     H000062   1     H000082
3     H000062   1     H000092
4     H000062   1     H000170
5     H000062   1     H000197
6     H000062   1     H000233
data1 <- aggregate(data[,2],data[,-2],sum)
data1 <- data1[order(data1$acentralacc,data1$bcentralacc),]
    head(data1)
   acentralacc bcentralacc  x
1      H000062     H000062 58
9      H000062     H000067 15
17     H000062     H000071 17
25     H000062     H000073 13
33     H000062     H000077 11
41     H000062     H000079 13
#vertices (ID,node attributs)
connStr <- "Driver={SQL Server};MyCon;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"
dsSqlServerData <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery = "SELECT  distinct CentralAccount,isnull(Team,'No Team') Team FROM MyTable2", connectionString = connStr)
users <- rxDataStep(dsSqlServerData)
    head(users)
  CentralAccount                         Team
1        H000062        ICT Customer Services
2        H000067            Financieel Beheer
3        H000070       Acceptatie Team 2 Gent
4        H000071       Acceptatie Team 1 Gent
5        H000073 NL Ond UW & Risk Advice Auto
6        H000076                      Incasso
#parsing (converting) users team
users$Team <- iconv(users$Team, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub="")
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=data1, vertices=users, directed=T) 
#the following should be igraph
class(net) 
#removing graphical loops etc
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T)
#creating color palet
pal2 <- rainbow(5, alpha=.5)
V(net)$color <- pal2[V(net)$Team]
plot(delete.vertices(simplify(net), degree(net)==0),vertex.size=5,vertex.label=NA,edge.arrow.size=.2)
legend("topleft", unique(c(V(net)$Team)), pch=21,col="#777777", pt.cex=2, cex=.8, bty="n", ncol=1)
```

This results in a graph with white vertexes and legend.

I've seen this post: [Generate colors based on unique entries in another list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349343/generate-colors-based-on-unique-entries-in-another-list-in-r)

Resulting in the following code

```
colrs<- brewer.pal(length(unique(V(net)$Team)), "Accent")  
names(colrs) <- unique(V(net)$Team)
V(net)$color <- colrs[V(net)$Team]      
V(net)$color
```

and it generates the following error

> Warning message: In brewer.pal(length(unique(V(net)$Team)), "Accent")
>   :   n too large, allowed maximum for palette Accent is 8 Returning the
>   palette you asked for with that many colors
>   Blockquote

i found a fix for that problem here; https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-expand-color-palette-with-ggplot-and-rcolorbrewer/

and this is what i made

```
install.packages("RColorBrewer")
library(RColorBrewer)

colourCount = length(unique(users$Team))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
colrs<- getPalette(colourCount)
names(colrs) <- unique(V(net)$Team)
V(net)$color <- colrs[V(net)$Team]  
V(net)$color
```

I have a colored (but messy) graph but my legend didn't change color, how do i fix this.

This line of code added to the legenda only colors the border of the circle infront of it and shows a weird colored square.
`fill=V(net)$color,col=V(net)$color`

[image: WeirdResult]

str(users)

```
'data.frame':   2481 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ CentralAccount: chr  "H000062" "H000067" "H000070" "H000071" ...
 $ Team          : chr  "ICT Customer Services" "Financieel Beheer" "Acceptatie Team 2 Gent" "Acceptatie Team 1 Gent" ...
```

Comment: You do not provide sample data and we do not have access to your SQLServer database, so we cannot reproduce your environment. However, it looks to me like `V(net)$Team` is a string, not a factor, so it cannot be used as an index into the vector colrs. You need to get the team as a number or a factor.

Comment: is there anygood way i can get out a sample dataset without sharing my whole database/ table? i've tried to give you guys the head() in the post so you got an idea what the data is like. but the whole table is 10 mil records.

Comment: I don't know your data,  but instead of `sqlQuery = "SELECT top 100000 * FROM MyTable1"`  How about `sqlQuery = "SELECT top 100 * FROM MyTable1"`?

Comment: yeah i select 100k or so records to get representable view, select top 100 would give the same data as the head() just a few more records. the reason why i'm not to keen on sharing to mutch data is cause its somewhat user data

Comment: OK,    how about sharing the output of `str(users)` ?

Comment: @G5W i've added it in the post

Comment: As I suspected,  users$Team  is just a character string. I _think_ it will work for you if you just include `users$Team <- factor(users$Team)` just before your statement `net <- graph_from_data_frame`

Comment: i'll add a picture of the weird "result", the result did not change