# R correlation network based on vertex attribute

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have a correlation network of all the users and how they are connected to each other based on their roles, and i've made the following plot:

```
plot(
    net,
    vertex.frame.color=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, "black",NA),
    vertex.size=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, 5, 0),
    vertex.label=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, NA, NA), 
    edge.arrow.mode=0,
    edge.lty=0,
    vertex.color=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, "skyblue", NA))
```

Resulting in: all the users but only the users of a certain team are collored
[image: Plot]
What i want to do is add the names of each user change vertex.label but this clutters the plot. since the users are so close together.

```
plot(
    net,
    vertex.frame.color=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, "black",NA),
    vertex.size=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, 5, 0),
    vertex.label=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, V(net)$internalname, NA), 
    edge.arrow.mode=0,
    edge.lty=0,
    vertex.color=ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName, "skyblue", NA))
```

Another thing is that we feel zoomed out, it would be way better if the plot would be centered on the visible users (`ifelse(V(net)$Team==TeamName`), i was thinking about subgraphs but i can't figure out how to do that exacly. And i don't know if this is the solution.

I have also tried this, this plot shows me that all my users are equaly correlated and the previous plot doesn't.

```
tem <-delete.vertices(net,V(net)$Team!=TeamName)
plot(tem, vertex.label= round(closeness(tem, mode="all", weights=NA),2))
```

Some Extra information, since i can not share personal data

dataframe that is used as edges (x is the amount of shared connections)

```
 $ acentralacc: chr  
 $ bcentralacc: chr  
 $ x          : int
```

dataframe that is used as vertex

```
  $ CentralAccount: chr  
  $ internalname  : chr 
  $ Team          : Factor
```

This should generate example data

```
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
#data1 (edges)
n<-100
acentralacc<- paste("user",sample(1:n, 1000,replace=TRUE)) #usera
bcentralacc<- paste("user",sample(1:n, 1000,replace=TRUE)) #userb
x<- sample(1:100, 1000,replace=TRUE) #x
data1 <- data.frame(acentralacc,bcentralacc,x)
head(data1)

#users (vertices)
centralacc <- unique(append(acentralacc, bcentralacc))
Team<- paste("Team",sample(1:round(n/3,0), length(centralacc),replace=TRUE))
users<-data.frame(centralacc,Team)
head(users)
```

other code

```
users$Team <- iconv(users$Team, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub="")
users$Team <- factor(users$Team)
#creating the igraph
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=data1, vertices=users, directed=T) 
#the following should be igraph
    class(net) 
#removing fields with no links (0 degree)(users with no connections)
    length(net[1])
net <- delete.vertices(simplify(net), degree(net)==0)
    length(net[1])
#removing graphical loops etc users that have connections to them self
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T)
```

Comment: Could you please type `dput(net)` and paste the results into your question so that we can work with your network?

Comment: Hi G5W you've tried to help me on another very similar question. unfortunaly i can't provide any personal data besides that the database is millions of records large. in my other question i have implemented the heads of the datasets i use and a sql query to produce similar data (since i don't know how to write that code in R)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602287/r-color-vertex-igraph). Is this enough for you to help me or can i do more without disclosing my entire dataset

Comment: @G5W i've added sample data

Comment: it seems that i have messed up my labels